# Check if no URL parameters been provided

Tags: python, django

I need to check an incoming URL in my view, if any parameter has been provided.

I've already checked various approaches with the request.GET option but did not find a suitable way. Most of them test for a defined parameter to be set, or none, like:

```
if self.request.GET.get('param'):
```

But what I need is the result when the URL is missing any parameter, like:

```
http://myapp/app/
```

instead of

```
http://myapp/app/?param=any
```

to set the queryset to a default.

Comment: If you set your URL in `urls.py` to receive an `arg` and you don't pass that `arg` Django will take of that for you and it'll complain. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with that code. It'd be helpful if you could explain what's the purpose of what you want.

Comment: `request.GET.get('param')` will give `None` if `param` is not set. Isn't that what you want? If not, please explain more precisely what you want, by showing us your specific code.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) specifies that `request.GET` is a **QueryDict**. Therefore, you should be able to check whether is empty by the number of keys.

```
if len(self.request.GET.keys()) == 0:
    print("There are no parameters")
```